# iOS - Facebook SDK method presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession not showing preview of request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I've implemented the basic function to send a invitation request to players' friends to play my game app on iOS devices.

I've followed the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-games/requests/

Everything works fine, I can send requests and friends receive notifications. The problem is that I cannot get the request dialog to appear the way is shown in the above link, in particularly I cannot get the request's preview in the dialog. Does this depend on SDK version? I am currently running with version SDK 3.5.3. Or the problem is somewhere else? any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Here's the code that calls the function:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Come and play CSR with me!"]
              title:nil
              parameters:params
              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                      NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                          NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                      }
                  }}];
```

Comment: It does not depend on the SDK version, it's completely controlled server side. What you're seeing is the new UI.

Comment: So there is no way of previewing the request message that will be sent?

Comment: Apparently, this is "By Design"!! :(   https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/605575982818621